# how do I clear interceptors?

Tags: interceptor, okhttp

I have single okhttp3 client from DI.
the provided client has interceptors that I want to clear.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder newOkHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder();
```

I am creating a new one using `newBuilder` but not sure I can clear interceptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using newbuilder() does not clear the existing interceptors. You can customize a shared OkHttpClient instance with newBuilder(). This builds a client that shares the same connection pool, thread pools, and configuration. Use the builder methods to configure the derived client for a specific purpose.

This link should help you:-
https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html